# Using a custom jquery plugin in a custom module

Tags: module

To use a jquery plugin in a control panel view the following is used in the module's mcp file:

```
ee()->cp->add_js_script(array('plugin' => 'dataTables'));
```

however I have a custom jqueru plugin, how do I load that into a control panel view? Where will the code above look for jquery plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Third party add-ons should store their javascript files in their *javascript* folder, and then loading them using:

```
ee()->cp->load_package_js('my_file');
```

[(Docs.)](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/cp.html#loading-third-party-javascript-files)

`ee()->cp->add_js_script()` will only load javascript which EE includes in the download for its own use.